# How to replace title with image in AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I replace the `AppBar` title with image logo in Flutter?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The `title` property takes a `Widget`, so you can pass any widget to it.

For example, an image added to assets

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Image.asset('assets/title.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
  ),
  body: ...
)
```

[More info](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/)

Comment: This is a good answer. I'd like to add that it made sense for me to make the image final:
```final Image titleImage = Image.asset(...)```
Without the image being final, it would lead to more rebuilds than the simple `Text` widget.

Comment: Hey @rgisi! May you add a link that clarifies it? I don't know how the build actually works under the hood and it would be great to know why making the `Image` final will skip some rebuilds. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 50):

```js
  appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                  Image.asset(
                 'assets/logo.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  height: 32,
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: Text('YourAppTitle'))
            ],

          ),
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to increase logo size? Seems it is limited by about 60

Comment: You must increase the parameter height, i.e.     height: XX,

Comment: If you want an AppBar taller you need to change the parameters to the AppBar

appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),

Comment: Thanks! But what if I need to make it flexible just relying on the child height only? By default appBar's height is constant (even with preferredSize param) and it clips all stuff inside. So I need to manipulate only child height but not both of appBar height and child height.

Comment: But what if you still need a back button on top the app bar and you are using a PreferredSize instead of AppBar?

Comment: how do you prevent the image in the appbar from overflowing if you shrink the webpage?

Answer (score 11):

App themes are probably best long term. (Make sure you've properly added the logo image to your assets folder and updated 'pubspec.yaml' file too).

1. Create a folder (e.g. 'themes') in your /lib path.
2. Create a "style" file (e.g. 'style.dart') in that folder. (Use this file also to implement different themes for your app: colors, fonts, etc.)
3. Create an image `widget` in your 'style' file, e.g. (height, weight, path, alignment up to you):

   ```
   Image appLogo = new Image(
   image: new ExactAssetImage("assets/images/AppLogo.png"),
   height: 28.0,
   width: 20.0,
   alignment: FractionalOffset.center);
   ```
4. In the `title` field of your `AppBar`, add 'appLogo' (or whatever you
   named the `widget`), like this (don't forget to import your 'style' file):

   ```
   child: Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: appLogo,        
   ),
   ```
5. Now, if ever you need to change this logo, you simply need to edit your style.dart file with the new image path and that's it. And if you have different themes and name your widgets the same way in each style file, you'll also be able to rapidly implement different styles (e.g. 'style1', 'style2', etc.) on the fly just by importing the respective file in just a couple places.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the AppBar does not fit it Height with the image size. To solve this problem, i've set the image and the AppBar Height (including the padding)

Here's my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Image.asset(
      "assets/images/logo_light.png",
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      height: 72,
    ),
    toolbarHeight: 88,
    actions: [
      IconButton(onPressed: () => {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  title: Image.asset('assets/your_logo.png', height: 32),
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the above didn't quite work for me, this adds the picture background I want to the entire app bar and leaves the option to keep a title.   updated for flutter/dart 2.0 null safety

```
Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('App Bar!'),
              flexibleSpace: Image(
                image: AssetImage('images/bar1.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
body: Container()

)
```