# The named parameter 'body' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with "body"

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

I'm just learning Flutter and I got such an error, but I entered the same commands as the video I watched, what should I do?

[Flutter Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YInFW.png)

Answer (score 1):

appBar class doesn't have a body attribute.
Follow the official documentation for more informations: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

If you want to use an image as a title see this topic : [How to replace title with image in AppBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983931/how-to-replace-title-with-image-in-appbar)